# Install a HD with Windows installed in a PC running Linux and add to GRUB

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub

This is my question.

I bought a PC **Lenovo** with **Windows 7** installed. After that, I upgrade to **Windows 10**. Finally, I removed the HD and mounted the HD of my current PC with Linux Mint. I have been using this PC for three years and am very happy.

I don't remember what I had to do to use the HD with W10 via USB, but sometimes I need to run any program under Windows, and I am able to do. It's in a case and I only must plug it to the computer and switch on the PC with the HD connected and it boots Windows. But it's quite slow.

So I wondered if I could take the HD with Windows, connect to PC via SATA, and add this HD to GRUB or whatever I must do. **Is it possible?** I know that ALWAYS Windows must be installed first, because Windows tries to erase other OSs.  My idea is to install the HD and do "something" for use without no more steps than configuring it in GRUB...if possible.

Comment: Sure. With os-prober `grub-mkconfig` / `update-grub` should be able to detect it and add an entry to the grub menu. The real problem is that if you've booted the Windows installation via USB, you will likely bump into problem if you boot it via SATA.

Comment: I´m afraid that I did it. But even I didn´t remember where I read the steps to do that, so I don´t know how could revert it, if it was possible.